# How to make my annotations beans available to XML configuration file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I am moving some beans definition from a XML to a @Configuration class, but there is one dependency that it will remain in the XML that requires one of those being moved. I read that @Configuration beans are loaded on the **Context** first than XML.

But I keep on getting this Exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityEventManagerImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jmsTopicTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="jmsTopicTemplate")}
```

The @Configuration bean are being loaded after the XML bean.

Anything that I am missing to make the @Configuration load first???

I tried doing @ComponentScan but it did not work.

Comment: I advice you to use a full java configuration instead an hybrid java with xml.  Share us an example and the xml

Comment: The XML is way too big, it has too many beans definitions, as part of this change I just need to move a couple. I considered that option but it would have a big impact and involved a big testing effort

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@ImportResource` annotation for this purpose, but generally you should keep the XML you are importing to a minimum, so you probably want to move the dependent beans to a separate file.